# JST-PHB does not seem to exist?

Tags: connectors

I am trying to find connectors with 2 pin rows and a lock mechanism and 2mm pitch.

The only source I can find them are [chinese sellers](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005005017465852.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2deu), and they label them as **JLT-PHB**, however, **looking through the [product catalog](https://www.jst.com/products/category/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/#page-4) of JLT, I can't find "PHB"**.

Are they sold under a different name?

[image]